# Facebook Graph API Requests from .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-ec2

I have an application that generates a web request to Facebook Graph API to get a share count from an external page.  I have been using this code for over a year without issue, and suddenly, the share count is not working when the request is made from .NET.  However, if I make the request from a web browser, it works just fine.  My code is as follows:

```
string fbLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=" + externalLink + "&fields=og_object%7Bengagement%7D&access_token=<token_removed>";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string fbString = client.DownloadString(fbLink);
```

This code still appears to be working fine, in that the request is made, and FB responds with no errors.  In fact, it responds back with correct page id, and details.  However, the share count is zero.

Here is where it gets a little bit weird.  On my localhost development machine, the code works fine and returns the proper share count.  However, if I run the code on my actual server (an AWS EC2 instance), the share count shows zero.

If I open Chrome and run the request from the browser, the share count displays as expected.

If I open Internet Explorer 11, and run the request from the browser, the counter shows zero.  **HOWEVER**, if I log in to Facebook from IE11, and then run the request to FB Graph API, the response shows the correct page count.

This is very confusing to me, as it appears the reason the counter has stopped working, has to do with cookies, or maybe the browser being logged into FB.  This should not be the case as I am using an APP token ID, and I wouldn't expect to need to be logged into FB in order to make a request to Graph API.

Does anybody have any ideas why my request/code in .NET worked just fine for a year and a half, and just stopped working? Or why the requests work fine on my localhost and not my live server?

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work anymore"? can you provide some more details as http status codes and error details? does it work in http clients like "postman" ? did you try to clear both browser caches and reproduce it?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, "does not work anymore" means that the share count is displayed as zero, instead of the actual number of shares.  There is no error code.  The status code returned is 200 OK, and all of the information contained in the response is correct, except the share count is incorrectly showing zero.  I have used several methods of generating the request, including WebClient, and HttpWebRequest.  The share count only shows zero when the request is made from my AWS EC2 server.  On my local machine, the same request generates a different response with the correct # of shares.

Comment: I have also looked at the Request/Response using Fiddler on both my local machine, and my live server.  The Request is the same on both, yet, the Response is different (showing zero on my EC2 server, and showing the correct number of shares on my local machine.

Comment: Okay..weird man, sorry think can't help you with that. But at least you know its not the code that breaks, its the server (or facebook) that changed something..

Comment: You’re not even specifying an API version in your call there, that might have something to do with it ...

Comment: I have specified versions 2.5 thru 2.10.  I get the same results no matter what version I specify.  The issue does not appear to be related to an incorrect request.  The issue is I get different responses depending on where or through what user agent I make the request, when the results should be independent of such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending considerable time on this issue, I have fixed the issue.  There is a FB authentication cookie that was being transmitted through a web browser query.  The cookie name was "XS" and the value was a long string that is used as a sessionId for my specific login.  If I created this cookie in my web request in C# code, I get the proper response with correct # of shares.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "xs=<removed>;");
```

I have no idea why I have to do this, only on my EC2 server.  Nowhere in FB's documentation does it say you have to spoof a valid logged in authentication string cookie in order to obtain correct Share Count results from a request to it's Graph API, but there you have it.  A workaround at least.